# php +codeigniter sql query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to do a query in my model from a table known as jurisdictions.  Now I want this query to provide a valid MySQL result resource. I.e I want to pass the result to `mysql_fetch_array()`.  If I pass in `$query = $this->db->query()`.  I get an error saying that the passed in argument is invalid.  I was wondering how can I convert `$query` to a MySQL result recource.

Comment: Why do you want to use mysql_fetch_array? I'm asking because you can do the same with codeigniter DBAL so you won't need to use that function normally.

Comment: I need to use it for some stuff in the view section.  I know I can easily do it like that but I need it for a drop down menu section.

Comment: You should never use any database code within the view. That's totally wrong and not the way codeigniter works. Instead prepare the data for the menu inside a model and pass the model to your view.

Comment: $query->conn_id will grab the driver object.. Perhaps you can work from this.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to have a MySQL resource, you should be using `mysql_query`.

Codeigniter already has a method which will give you one row at a time: [`row_array`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) (actually, it has two, the other is just `row`, but that returns an object, not an array). If you want to get numeric indexes on the result of result_array, use array_values:

```
$result = $this->db->query( "SELECT 'foo' as foo_rules FROM DUAL" );
$aso_arr = $result->row_array(); // assoc. array w/o numeric indexes
echo $aso_arr[ 'foo_rules' ];
$num_arr = array_values( $aso_arr );
echo $num_arr[ 0 ];
```

If you would like the entire result of the selection, then use `result` and `result_array` (they have behavior similar to row and row_array, only they return the whole result set in an array)

### EDIT

I repeat my first sentence, but you can get the MySQL resource this way:

```
$result = $this->db->query( "SELECT 'foo' as foo_rules FROM DUAL" );
$resource = $result->result_id;
```

But, since this is not documented, it should not be considered supported or even expected behavior. Be forewarned.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly then why not just use the available methods of:

```
$query->result();
```

or

```
$query->result_array();
```

Choose whichever to suit your needs.

Comment: No I need to be able to pass in my query object to the mysql_fetch_array function.  I just need a way to convert $query to a mysql recource..I dont want to convert it to an array beforehand.